# PHP - find most common word over certain character length in string.

Tags: php, count

Ok, so as I'm getting my hands dirty with PHP I've started playing around with arrays, strings and the like.

Now I know that arrays have a neat feature called "array_count_values" which can help to determine what the most repeated entry is. I wasn't able to find a string equivalent for this- will I need to convert the string to an array?

Basically, I want my code to determine what the most common (repeated) word is over a certain length in a given string.

Sans the character length qualification, this code can find the answer to the question of what is the most repeated word in an array:

```
<?php


$param[0]="Ted";
$param[1]="Mark";
$param[2]="Mark";
$param[3]="Ross"; 
$param[3]="Clarence"; 

function array_most_common($arr) 
{ 
  $counted = array_count_values($arr); 
  arsort($counted); 
  return(key($counted));     
}

$mostCommon = array_most_common($param);
echo $mostCommon;
?>
```

So what would make this doable with a string? And a character amount filter?

Comment: I don't get what you mean about doing it with a string. Aren't those strings you're working with?

Comment: I see the answers, they must be right that what you want is to explode one long string into an array of words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a string, you can just [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) or [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) on space to form an array. Using `preg_split()` is favorable as it will eliminate duplicate and extraneous whitespace that `explode()` will not.

```
$array = preg_split( '/\s+/', "This is a pretty long long long string", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Then, once you have an array, use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove those that don't meet the character requirements:

```
$threshold = 3;
$filtered = array_filter( $array, function( $el) use( $threshold) {
    return strlen( $el) > $threshold;
});
```

Once you have the `$filtered` array, just use that in [`array_count_values()`](http://php.net/array_count_values).

```
$counts = array_count_values( $filtered);
arsort( $counts); 
echo key( $counts) . ' -> ' . current( $counts);
```

[Here](http://viper-7.com/S8TQC8) is a demo, which prints:

```
long -> 3
```

Comment: But how would I go about filtering words over or under a certain character limit?

So it would be number of times repeated + character limit = printed results.

Comment: @SiriusMane - It's in my answer, `array_filter()`.

Comment: When I modify the threshold variable (even up to 6 or so) it will still display "long" as the answer. If I add in the words "chubby chubby chubby" it will select it- if it's in front of "long" in the string. If the reverse is true it will still display long as the answer.

Comment: So unless I'm missing something, it's not filtering based on the amount of repeated words and character length..

Comment: @SiriusMane - There was a small bug in that `$array` was being passed to `array_count_values()` instead of `$filtered`. It's fixed now, and if you put the `$threshold` to `5` in the new demo, you'll get different results.

Comment: Thanks.. I'm just trying to pour through this to grasp it in and out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, there is not a function for determining the most common word in a string as far as I'm aware. However, you can `explode()` the string by space, and `array_count_values()` the resulting array instead. I'm not too certain what you mean by a "character amount filter" or where you plan to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = strtolower("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
$words = explode(" ", $str);
$words = array_filter($words, function($word) {
    return strlen($word) > 2;
});
$word_counts = array_count_values($words);
arsort($word_counts);
$most_common_word = key($word_counts); // Returns "the"
```